# How do I apply a class to all links on a specific page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page on WordPress with hundreds of links and I'd like to style them all with a CSS class without having to add the class to each link, line by line, and want to use JavaScript to do it.

How can I achieve this?

I want only https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/ to be affected using my CSS class, "link-style"

I found a response on another similar thread with this:

`document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+document.URL+'"]').forE‌​ach(function(elem){e‌​lem.className += ' current-link')});`

I tried it, probably incorrectly, with this:

`document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'*https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/*'"]').forE‌ach(function(elem){e‌lem.className += 'link-style')});`

Am I doing it wrong or am I not using the correct solution, or both?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: give them a common `className` after that `document.querySelectorAll('.common-class').forEach((link) => { link.style.color = 'red' });`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The class I set in my stylesheet is: .link-style.  Wouldn't that be the common class used for this action?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const URL = "https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/";

document
    .querySelectorAll(`a[href="${URL}"]`)
    .forEach(element => element.classList.add('link-style'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this but unfortunately didn't see any changes occur, even after clearing my site and browser caches. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's no reason for this to not work. Are you sure the `href` attribute is *exactly* `https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/`?

Comment: Yes it's exactly the same. Perhaps it's Elementor overriding it? Hard to say. Looking under the hood to try and see what could be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/"]')].forE‌ach(function(elem){e‌lem.classList.add('link-style')});
```

it checks all href starting from

```
https://staging.startupdevkit.com/resource-library-version-1/
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which also has a `forEach` method. Spreading into an array is therefore not necessary.